# MS Word: LaTeX-style object placement?

Tags: microsoft-word, layout

If I place a figure or table in LaTeX which does not fit on the remainder of a page, LaTeX resumes the flow of the text, and plots the object on the top or bottom of the next page. Later paragraphs will flow around the object, using the available page space efficiently.

I am wondering: Is something similar possible in Word, and if so: how? My current workflow merely consists of manual page breaks to achieve this, which is not very elegant.

Comment: The answer below states that this is not possible in Word. And unfortunately it is not possible in OpenOffice/LibreOffice either. Why such an obvious (and powerful) feature is not considered is a mystery to me, and it disqualifies Word and OO/LO for any big technical document with figures all along the text... Decades ago it was possible in FrameMaker. I submitted a development request for LO years ago, and had many difficulties to simply make the developers understand that it was not a minor feature... Since that, nothing happened...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid this feature is not available in Word. In the 39 years the software exists, MS has not found a way to handle images elegantly and efficiently.

If your situation allows for it, you could keep writing in LaTeX and then [transform the resulting document to Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111886/13134), either using [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) or by opening the [resulting PDF in Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263017/13134). This allows you to keep using part of the "brains" of LaTeX, while simultaneously meeting the requirement of using Word.

Comment: Using pandoc to convert to word does not allow using the "brains" of tex, its a mostly compatible independent haskell implementation of the underlying tex engine, but that can result in issues if you wish to use some of latexs more complex features.

Comment: Fair point, I guess it depends on what one means with "brains". E.g. figure placement with options like `[htpb]` doesn't work, but poiting LaTeX to an image via a path does work. Sure, for the latter there is Word's `INCLUDEPICTURE` field, but it's quite buggy and often breaks links inexplicably.

Comment: For what it's worth, LaTeX doesn't handle them elegantly or efficiently, either. You may have to run LaTeX multiple times to get correct placement.

Comment: InDesign for the win? :-D

Comment: @user253751 ;) have you been recently hurt in a long LaTeX typesetting struggle? Sure its not a global optimal solution, but compared to Word its pure gold (if you put in the time to learn using it). And then we haven't even considered things like pgfplot, which allow you to render graphs in the style of the document from provided data.

Comment: @oakad I'm not sure which has a steeper learning curve :)

Comment: @user253751 Why is "run multiple times" not "elegant"? Just use latexmk and it will automatically run LaTeX the exact number of times needed.

Comment: (Although you might have a point for "efficient". That having said I haven't benchmarked Word yet, there are some cases it's quite inefficient as well and there are alternatives to LaTeX that are/might be more efficient (ever heard of ConTeXt/OpTeX/plain TeX? Some are more efficient by being simpler, some uses the power of Lua to do the computationally heavy work))

Comment: @user202729 why **is** it elegant?

Comment: @user253751 Up to you then. I'm not forcing you to use anything, just refusing your argument.

Comment: @user253751 perhaps a good question for [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: in Word simply make the image float instead of inline and you can move it anywhere

Comment: @phuclv ...and if you modify the document anywhere before where the image is, the anchor of the image can jump from one page to another and so does the image, with unpredictable results (collision with other floating images, etc..). Actually each floating image position has to be checked after any modification in the document, which is unfeasible with long documents containing many images.

Comment: @phuclv what if I need to update all my images in a 50 page document? Or what if I want to shrink the width of all images by 10%? How does that work in Word?